# SwipeRefreshLayout + Webview: How to scroll a Scrollable modal without triggering swipe refresh

Tags: android, reactjs, webview, modal-dialog, swiperefreshlayout

I'm running into an issue with SwipeRefreshLayout and my Webview. The swipe refresh works fine on the base page of the Webview even if the page is scrollable (you're able to scroll back up to the top without triggering a swipe refresh).

However, when I open a `scrollable modal`, any swipe down gesture (even ones to scroll the modal back up) triggers the swipe refresh.

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I've tried only enabling the `swipeRefreshLayout` when `webview.getScrollY() == 0`, however, when I open the modal, the `getScrollY()` gets reset to `0` automatically, rendering that solution meaningless.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?